# Migrating data from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

I have to migrate existing data which is in `SQL Server 2000` to `SQL Server 2005`. The schema of two databases is different. For Example `Locations` table in SS2000 is split into two tables and has different columns. **This is one time activity. After successful migration I don't need old db anymore.**

- What is the best way to transfer data from one SQL Server to another having different schemas?

I can write stored procedures to fetch data from `SQL Server 2000` and `insert/update` tables in `SQL Server 2005`.

- What about `SSIS`? I don't have any experience with this and is this better to create package of `SSIS` because I don't need this again and need to learn it first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case you will have to write specific transformation logic since your schemas are different, even with SSIS.  There is nothing that will be able to discern where to put things in the new schema just by comparing the two schemas.

SSIS has utilities to help you develop that transormation in a more visual style but if you are unfamiliar with SSIS then it can have a bit of a learning curve.  My opinion is that you're better off writing stored procedures for just a one time migration.